# Google not indexed url

Tags: sitemap, indexed

Hello i have personal site and about 1 month ago i rebuild the complete site. I sent a new  sitemap.xml file and is not indexed yet, but im having 404 crawler errors with the old url.

Google said the sitemap is correct,so, any idea, i must do something, or just wait longer?
Is not really important because is just a personal site, but i`m just curious about what is that happening.

Sorry for my bad english, but im  spanish and thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a google service.

Answer (score 0):

this just takes time.
I experienced some speed-up in that progress by using other google services as places or analytics. but to answer your question:

If your sitemap has been detected correctly it will work but this might take some time.

Comment: just to add as beside information, that indexing time is (in my experience) not influenced by the quality of seo provided by the page at that time. you will find it on google. when it's finally indexed you gotta provide the quality of your seo to rank up. (that's my experience. not what google says about the indexing. haha, google sayin something about the indexing...)